# Equivalent definitions of continuity in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and let $f: X \to Y$ be a function. I need to prove the following statements are equivalent:

1. $f$ is continuous
2. $\forall A \subseteq X, f[Cl_X(A)] \subseteq Cl_Y(f[A])$
3. $\forall B \subseteq Y, Cl_X(f^{-1}[B]) \subseteq f^{-1}[Cl_Y(B)]$

Where $Cl_X(A)$ is the closure of $A$ in $X$ and $Cl_Y(B)$ is the closure of $B$ in $Y$.
I must to use this, and only this definition of continuity:

$f$ is continuous at $x_0 \in X$ $\iff$ for all $A \subseteq Y$ open, $f(x_0) \in A$, $\exists B \subseteq X$ open, $x_0 \in B$, such that $f[B] \subseteq A$.

Until now, I have proved $1) \implies 2)$ and $1) \implies 3)$, but is really difficult for me to prove the other way.

$2) \implies 1)$: Let $x_0 \in X$ arbitrary. Let $A$-open of $Y$ such that $f(x_0) \in A$. Define $B = X\setminus f^{-1}[A]$. Note that, $f[B] \subseteq Y\setminus A$, which is closed. Hence, by 2)

$f[Cl_X(B)] \subseteq Cl_Y(f[B]) \subseteq Y\setminus A$

Since, $f(x_0) \in A$, $f(x_0) \notin Y\setminus A$, then $x_0 \notin Cl_X(B)$. That is, $x_0 \in X\setminus Cl_X(B) \subseteq X\setminus B = f^{-1}[A]$.

Then, $f[X\setminus Cl_X(B)] \subseteq f[f^{-1}[A] \subseteq A$. That is, $f$ is continuous. But I feel I am not using right 2).

I would really appreciate it if you could give me some hints to approach this exercise and $3) \implies 1)$ using that definition of continuity.

Comment: Note that $x_0 \notin B$ does not imply that $x_0 \notin {\rm Cl} B$, since it is not generally true that ${\rm Cl} B \subseteq B$.

Comment: @K.Jiang  Corrected. I was precisely using the definition that I can't use, I was assuming $f^{-1}[A]$ open.

Comment: It may be easier with the following relation: Take in (3) complements on both sides (and use the fact that $(cl(A)^C=int(A^C)$). Then you see that (3) is equivalent to the statement: (4) $f^{-1}(intB) \subset int f^{-1}(B)$. int - denoting the interior of a set